# "State of the art" algorithms deciding entailment of propositional formulas?

Tags: algorithms, propositional-logic

I fail to find much about how to efficiently calculate whether a propositional formula entails another.

Considering the following two points...

1. We can check, for each truth assignment which makes the first formula true, whether it also makes the second true. If all of them do, the first entails the second. It works for disjunctive normal forms, conjunctive normal forms, ... anything really. But this can be prohibitively expensive for large numbers of propositions.
2. If we translate both formulas to disjunctive normal form we can more efficiently check for entailment, but we need to do the transformation to DNF first.

... what are the best algorithms to check entailment?

I was under the impression that this must be a problem that's long been solved, but where are the papers that deal with entailment of arbitrary propositional formulas? How do I calculate a yes/no answer without using DNFs?

Answer (score 1):

Checking whether $P \Rightarrow Q$ is the same as checking that $P \land \lnot Q$ is unsatisfiable. Using the [Tseytin transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tseytin_transformation), you can convert $P \land \lnot Q$ into a form suitable for a SAT solver.

Conversely, satisfiability is a special case of your problem, since $P \Rightarrow \bot$ iff $P$ is unsatisfiable.

Comment: What is the advantage of transforming to CNF (which Wikipedia tells me is the result of a Tseytin transformation) and then solving as opposed to transforming to DNF and then solving? I'm more interested in understanding the algorithms, less so in quickly implementing the best practical way to solve a given problem.

Comment: SAT solvers solve the satisfiability problem, which doesn't make much sense for DNFs (it's very easy).

Comment: The point of this answer is that your question is a special case of SAT. We already know how to solve SAT in practice – that's the area of SAT solving.

Comment: Yes, does that mean your answer includes "look at algorithms for SAT solvers" in some way? Solving my problem using DNFs seems pretty straight forward, but I thought one might be able to solve it without transforming into a normal form first.

Comment: Satisfiability is a *special case* of your problem.

Comment: Yes, but if solving a DNF is, as you say, very easy, why "go to the trouble" of using a SAT solver, when it doesn't even get rid of the need to transform to normal form first? (Is it because a Tseytin transformation is much more efficient than transforming to DNF - or rather, is the combination of Tseytin+SAT that much faster than DNF+VeryEasy?)

Comment: Tseytin transformation runs in linear time.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good argument for Tseytin transformations.

Comment: The negation of a DNF is a CNF (and vice versa). This could explain the confusion between CNFs and DNFs.

Comment: Yes, I am aware. So in a sense the question is more "Negation+VeryEasy versus SAT solver", as one could use Tseytin transformation + Negation to arrive at a DNF. I will check whether using a SAT solver will work for me.